# Как сделать output ffmpeg инпутом для другого?

Tags: ffmpeg

Мне нужно объединить текст, аудио и видео в один файл mp4. Для этого я использую эти две команды в .bat файле

`ffmpeg -i %video_file% -i %audio_file% -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 %output_file_name% -shortest`

`ffmpeg -i %output_file_name% -vf "drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='Powered by SANTA ltd.':fontcolor=white:fontsize=96:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -c:a copy output_font.mp4`

Первая объединяет аудио + видео, а вторая мержит с текстом посередине экрана.

Как из этих двух команд сделать пайп? Чтоб вместо двух команд использовалась одна?

Comment: @andreymal - Да, у меня тоже такой же вопрос возник, может, оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ?

Comment: я как то начинал изучать опции ffmpeg... и понял, что это целая отдельная вселенная

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как я уже написал в комментарии, пайп вам не нужен, но всё же стоит соблюсти формальность и ответить на вопрос, поставленный в заголовке.

Чтобы ffmpeg выводил в стандартный вывод, нужно вместо имени файла указать `-` (дефис). Чтобы ffmpeg читал что-то из стандартного ввода, нужно аналогично указать дефис на входе `-i -`.

Обычно ffmpeg определяет формат вывода по расширению файла, но так как стандартный вывод не имеет расширения, придётся вручную указать нужный формат, например `-f mp4`

Однако конкретно с MP4 есть проблема: он по умолчанию не рассчитан на стриминг и требует seekable вывод (то есть возможность перескочить в произвольное место файла), и при выводе MP4 в стандартный вывод получится ошибка `muxer does not support non seekable output`.

Это можно исправить с помощью опций вывода `-movflags +frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof` — таким образом ffmpeg будет постепенно записывать отдельные кусочки MP4, разделённые по ключевым кадрам, что пригодно для стриминга и не требует seekable вывода.

Касательно «raw» и «указывать размеры видео» — ничего подобного не требуется, так как формат mp4 уже содержит внутри себя всю необходимую информацию, и ffmpeg прекрасно её прочитает.

Таким образом, общая схема такая:

`ffmpeg [опции] -f mp4 -movflags +frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof - | ffmpeg -i - [опции]`

В вашем случае вот такая громадина должна сработать:

`ffmpeg -i %video_file% -i %audio_file% -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -shortest -f mp4 -movflags +frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof - | ffmpeg -i - -vf "drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='Powered by SANTA ltd.':fontcolor=white:fontsize=96:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -c:a copy output_font.mp4`

В качестве альтернативы можно для пайпа использовать формат Matroska (mkv), который изначально пригоден для стриминга (выходной файл всё равно можно сделать mp4 при желании):

`ffmpeg [опции] -f matroska - | ffmpeg -i - [опции]`

---

Однако в вашем случае пайп совершенно не нужен, так как достаточно просто взять и нарисовать текст на видео в первой команде вместо копирования этого самого видео. Но если уж [базовая структура аргументов ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Description) почему-то не знакома, то ладно, вот ответ...

Кратко:

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.flac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='Powered by SANTA ltd.':fontcolor=white:fontsize=96:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -c:a aac -shortest output_font.mp4`

Подробно:

```sh
ffmpeg
# Опция -i задаёт входной файл. Перед ней можно указать дополнительные
# опции для указанного входа (но в данном случае опции не требуются)
# Первый вход получит номер 0
-i video.mp4
# Второй вход получит номер 1
-i audio.flac
# Опция -i здесь больше не встречается, поэтому все дальнейшие опции
# применяются к выходному файлу
# Указываем, какие дорожки должны попасть в итоговый файл
# Первое видео из файла 0 и первое аудио из файла 1
-map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0
# Кодек для видео не указан, будет использовано что-то по умолчанию
# При желании можно указать кодек опцией "-c:v libx264" и битрейт "-b:v 4000k"
# Применение фильтра drawtext к видео перед его кодированием
# Можно указать несколько фильтров через запятую, но здесь фильтр один
# https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1
-vf "drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='Powered by SANTA ltd.':fontcolor=white:fontsize=96:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2"
# Кодек для аудио — AAC, битрейт какой-то по умолчанию
-c:a aac
# Завершаем запись файла, когда закончится любая из аудио/видео дорожек
-shortest
# Название выходного файла. Формат mp4 определяется автоматически по расширению
output_font.mp4
# Дальше можно указать опции для следующего выходного файла,
# но в данном случае файл нужен один, так что всё
```